# How do I link a react app I am building using webpack to a phpmyadmin external database and query it without showing my database password in the code?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, webpack

So I am currently learning react and webpack so that I can implement it into my current site. I already have an established phpmyadmin database that pumps out information that I want to appear on my site but I cant figure out how to hide my username and password to the database when programming it. I am used to using php to interact with my database bus since react is purely javascript I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a server running that talks to your database and to your react app. It sounds like you *might* have this in the form of a PHP application. Your PHP application will need to expose data over HTTP endpoints that you can then fetch from inside of your React application.

This tutorial: https://www.techiediaries.com/php-react-rest-api-crud-tutorial/ would be a great place for you to get started.

Comment: Oooh ok. Thanks for the reply! So just to clarify, I would basically have to program a bunch of php functions that interact with the database and return json data. Then call said functions as needed inside of my react app using axios?

Comment: That's the basic idea! The general flow is: 

database --> server-side database queries -> expose the results of the queries over HTTP, formatted as json or another data type -> fetch the HTTP endpoints (via axios, fetch api, etc.) in your React components.

Comment: Please remove that link from the answer. It promotes bad practice (string concatenation to build SQL), which leads to serious vulnerabilities in software. This type of vulnerability is called 'SQL injection' and can lead to unauthorized access to the database. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you need to "have a server running that talks to your database and to your react app" as the accepted answer states. On the other hand this does not mean that you have to code it from scratch.

If you don't want to program PHP for the back-end, then you may as well configure software from [the list of 'automatic APIs'](https://github.com/dbohdan/automatic-api). An automatic API is "software that turns your database into a REST/GraphQL API".

I'm the author of [PHP-CRUD-API](https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api), which is an 'automatic API' and I think it suits your needs, but you may as well use any other software from the above list.